# OpenCL Maximum Size of Private Memory per Work Item

Tags: gpu, opencl, amd-gpu

I Have an AMD RX 570 4G,
OpenCL tells me that I can use a Maximum of 256 Workgroup and 256 WorkItem per group...

Let's say I use all 256 Workgroup with 256 WorkItem in each of them,

Now, What is the Maximum Size of private memory per work item?

Is Private memory Equal to Total VRAM (4GB) Divided by Total Work Items (256x256)?

Or is it equal to cache if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private memory space is registers on the GPU die (0 cycle access latency) and not related to the amount of VRAM (global memory space) at all. The amount of private memory depends on the device (private memory per compute unit).
I don't know private memory size for the RX 570, but for older HD7000 series GPUs it is 256kB per CU. If you have a work group size of 256, you get 1kB per work item, which is equal to 256 float variables.

Cache size determines the size of local and constant memory space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!
[rx 570](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-rx-570.c2939#:~:text=AMD%20has%20paired%204%20GB,MHz%20(7%20Gbps%20effective).) Here it shows i got 16KB per CU And 32 CU, 
So is it a total of 512 KB for 256 Work Group? with 2 KB per work item?
Please tell me if there is something wrong with this calculation!

Comment: Divide the 16kB private memory per CU by the 256 work items that run in parallel on one CU, then you get 64B per thread, equivalent to 16 floats. If you need more, you can divert to constant memory space for lookup tables or to local memory space which is read/write and shared across work items within a workgroup. Both constant and local are part of cache and have low latency access.

Comment: Once again Thanks for answering, [rx 570](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-rx-570.c2939#:~:text=AMD%20has%20paired%204%20GB,MHz%20(7%20Gbps%20effective).) Is Local and Constant memory located in the L2 cache? since Private is Stored in L1 Cache... Am i correct?

Comment: Private memory is in registers, located right next to the arithmetic logic units of the scream processors. Register access is even faster than cache access (0 cycle latency), but very limited in size. Local memory is part of L1 cache (4-8 cycle latency) and constant memory is in L1 and L2 cache or global memory (400-800 cycle latency) if L2 is not enough.

Comment: thanks for elaborating about Local and constant!

Comment: Hello! sorry for asking this question this late `Divide the 16kB private memory per CU by the 256 work items that run in parallel on one CU, then you get 64B per thread` Here it says 64Byte per work item when there are 256 work items. My question is What about **Work_Group** * 256? wouldn't it be 64/Work_Group?

Comment: One workgroup is executed on one CU at a time. The private memory of one CU splits up upon the work items of the one workgroup running on it. A GPU has multiple CUs, so multiple workgroups can run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for Replying! if one Only one group executes at a time In one Cu, then isn't it better to have Total Work Group == Compute Unit?
instead of WorkGroup == CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE?

Comment: The workgroup size is a parameter that can be freely tuned for best performance and/or to avoid spill from private to global memory. Workgroup size must be a multiple of 32. Smaller workgroup means more private memory per thread (less risk of spill to global), but less communication capability over local memory (performance loss, only if you use local memory for optimization).

Comment: `Smaller workgroup means more private memory per thread` let's say I have 256 Workgroup and 256 Work Item per group(total 256x256 work item),
Would i have `64B per thread(workitem)` or less like `Memory per thread = 64B/256WorkGroup`?

Comment: You would have 64B per thread. The number of work groups has no influence on the amount of prvate memory per thread.

Answer (score 2):

VRAM is represented in OpenCL as global memory.

Private memory is initially allocated from the register file. Your RX 570 is from AMD's Polaris architecture, a.k.a. [GCN 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next) where each compute unit (64 shader processors) has access to 256 vector (SIMD) registers (64x32 bits wide) and 512 32-bit scalar registers. So that works out to about 66KiB per CU, but it's not as simple as just quoting that total.

A workgroup will always be scheduled on a single compute unit, so if you assign it 256 work items, then it will have to perform every vector instruction 4 times in sequence (64 x 4 = 256) and the vector registers will (simplifying slightly) effectively have to be treated as 64 256-entry registers.

Scalar registers are used for data and calculations which are identical on each work item, e.g. incrementing a loop counter, holding buffer base pointers, etc.

Private memory will usually spill to global if you use more than will fit in your register file. So performance simply drops.

So essentially, on GCN, your optimal workgroup size is usually 64. Use as little private memory as possible; definitely aim for less than *half* of the available register file so that more than one workgroup can be scheduled so latency from memory access can be papered over, otherwise your shader cores will be spending a lot of time just waiting for data to arrive or be written out.

Cache is used for OpenCL local and constant memory spaces. (Constant will again spill to global if you try to use too much. The size of local memory can be checked via the OpenCL API and again is divided among workgroups scheduled on the same compute unit, so if you use more than half, only one group can run on a CU, etc.)

I don't know where you're getting a limit of 256 workgroups from, the limit is essentially set by whether the GPU uses 32-bit or 64-bit addressing. Most applications won't get close to 4bn work items even in the 32-bit case.

Comment: Thanks for Answering! as for the Workgroup and Workitem I used the below opencl function I get maximum Workgroup and WorkItem per group...

`clGetDeviceInfo(ChosenGPU, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(temp), &temp, NULL);
clGetDeviceInfo(ChosenGPU, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES, sizeof(temp), &temp, NULL);`

Also is it better to run with 64 work items per work group to run in parallel without any sequences?

Comment: @PunalManalan both `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` and `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` are about work items *in a workgroup*, not global size. If your device supports 3 dimensions, and your work groups are A x B x C = G items large, then G must be less than or equal to the value returned for `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`, and each of A, B, and C must be less than or equal to the 3 array entries returned for `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`.

Comment: @PunalManalan I don't know what you mean by "without any sequences," please explain.

Comment: @pmjd I was referring to this Part `4 times in sequence (64 x 4 = 256)`
I mistook it as 64 Work Items * 4 times in one by one order...
My mistake Sorry!
And once again Thanks a lot for Answering my question!

Comment: @PunalManalan What I meant by this is: The CUs in AMD GCN GPUs can "only" execute 64 work-items in parallel. So if you use a workgroup size larger than this, it will be split into subgroups of 64 items each, and each of these subgroups will be scheduled to run on the same CU. So if you don't need your group size to be that large, you are better off using 64-item groups, as your work can better be distributed across CUs.

Comment: Once Again thanks for explaining in detail! Can you please tell me why [Gtx 1060](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1060-6-gb.c2862) is faster even though it has 10 SM(CU?) and only 1280 Shading unit while [rx 570](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-rx-570.c2939#:~:text=AMD%20has%20paired%204%20GB,MHz%20(7%20Gbps%20effective).) has 32 CU and 2048 Shading unit?

Comment: @PunalManalan Different GPUs are optimised for different workloads, and small aspects of a compute kernel can sometimes have very large impact on performance. Without seeing profiling data and source code there really isn't anything more I can say about it.

Comment: Thanks, I only have an Rx 570 so I can't exactly give any data about the Gtx 1060 OpenCL code.
As Gtx 1060 being faster than Rx 570 i was referring to the gaming benchmarks, 
Since On paper Rx 570 has Triple the Cores and Double the shaders Than Gtx 1060, I was wondering shouldn't it outperform Gtx 1060 in all aspects?

Comment: Thanks pmdj. I've observed the private to global memory spill once on a V100 while other GPUs didn't do it. Good to know the cause!

Comment: @PunalManalan Gaming performance is influenced by a lot more than just number and clock rate of shader cores. Especially important for rendering is fill rate - i.e. pixel processing rate (performed by ROPs) and texture filtering rate (performed by TMUs). Note how the GTX 1060's theoretical pixel fill rate is about twice that of the RX 570. ROPs are largely unused in OpenCL as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @pmdj `ROPs are largely unused` Is there a way to Use ROPs? in mathematical calculations?
If not then, is AMD architecture Better than Nvidia in terms of OpenCL Performance?

Comment: A ROP performs pixel blending. So if your mathematical operation is equivalent to one of the supported blend modes, and your data can be represented by an image, then yes you can use it; implement it as a draw operation in OpenGL/Vulkan/Direct3D/Metal. In most cases though, this isn't terribly practical.

Comment: Older AMD cards definitely were much than older Nvidia cards **at integer operations.** I think Nvidia has caught up in the last few generations. (Maybe Turing & Ampere?) Floating point wise it's been similar performance for similar price for a long time, with winner and loser depending on the exact details of the workload and for which one you've optimised your kernels…

Comment: @pmdj If My workload consists **ONLY** of floating-point -+/* and Comparison operators Then is AMD more suitable than Nvidia? since I won't be utilizing ROP or any pixel processing...

Comment: @PunalManalan It'll also depend on memory access patterns, register pressure, local memory usage, branching/loop constructs used, level of vectorisation, etc. Based on pure FP32 FLOPS the RX570 should be faster than the GTX1060 though, yes.

Comment: @pmdj Thanks a Lot! this is very helpful!