# OpenCL maximum number of work groups for a device

Tags: opencl

I am learning OpenCL and using a RTX 2060.

Based on what I read online the maximum number of work items for this device  is 1024 and the maximum work items per work group is 64 (which means I can run 16 work groups of 64 work items right?)

Question is : **is there a limit to the number of work groups themselves?** For example can I run 32 work groups of 32 work items? 64 work groups of 16 work items? 512 work groups of 2 work items? (you get the idea).

Answer (score 0):

The vendor only specifies a value for the maximum size of a workgroup; for Nvidia this is usually 1024. But it is still allowed (although not really useful) to choose even larger workgroup size. The larger the workgroup, the less registers (`private` variables) you can have per thread, and if you use too many (like many thousand in a table) they spill into global memory which makes things very slow. For details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66917247/9178992).

Note that workgroup size should be 32 or a multiple of 32 to best utilize the hardware.

There is no limit for the number of workgroups. You only will eventually run out of memory. In general, the more workgroups the better, because then the device is fully saturated and no SMs are idle at any time. It is not uncommon to have 2 Million workgroups of 32 threads each.